# How to remove or disable Siri in all apps?

Tags: ios, siri

In the iOS settings, there is a list of apps.  Under each app, there is a setting to "Allow Siri to learn from how you use "APP"...  How can I disable this for all apps?

iOS version: 17.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a “per App setting;” there is no global setting for this.   You’ll need to go through each one and turn them off individually.

From [imore.com](https://www.imore.com/how-stop-siri-learning-how-you-use-apps-iphone-and-ipad)

> Unfortunately, in iOS 15, there's no universal switch to stop Siri from learning from apps en masse, so you'll need to go through this process for every app you wish to exclude from Siri personalization.